# SPD2013 Workflow - while loop

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-designer

Is there any difference in a SPD2013 workflow between using the "Loop with condition" action and having a stage transition to itself given certain conditions? Can a stage even transition to itself and are there any limitations?